# All USB devices that were connected, EVER

Tags: usb, usb-device

How do I find all the USB devices that were connected, since the installation of the OS?

I suspect that the path `/var/run/udev/data` has this info, but not sure.

In addition, how do I filter the results in order to find only keyboards OR flash drives?

Comment: I very much doubt this is possible. What makes you think that data is stored?

Comment: @terdon Linux keeps all kinds of history, why not keeping USB devices? It can be left as a "forgotten" file...

Comment: because a forgotten file whose size increases every time you connect a device, is not a good idea. Note that the answer you received won't work for "for ever". Don't expect it to show every device you've ever connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system log file will be updated when USB devices are connected. It is usually located in `/var/log/syslog` in Debian-based distros, and `/var/log/messages` in RedHat-based distros.

The age of the log file can vary, as some systems will "rotate" log files once they reach a certain size, or discard older entries altogether. These settings are stored in `/etc/syslog.conf`

You can search text files using `grep`, for example

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'usb'`

The exact syntax will depend on your system: check the log after connecting a device to see what entries will look like.

You can search for multiple terms at once using regular expressions (regex). The pipe `|` character indicates 'either/or', for example.

`grep '(usb-storage|usb-keyboard)'`

(More on regex [here.][https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux])

EDIT: As others have noted, this is not a permanent log.  As far as I am aware, there is no log that will contain **all** events stretching back to the date of installation.